# Word or phrase for water coming out of clothes

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

I was looking for a simple word or phrase to describe how sometimes, water comes out of wet clothes and spill on the floor. For example if you handwash your clothes and hang them up to dry but you don't wring them out first. So the water is spilling all over. How to say this?  water coming down the clothes, water coming out of the clothes, water spilling down the clothes or something else? Because these all sound wrong to me.

Answer (score 7):

In your example (wet clothes hanging on a line) the verb is **drip**:

> Water is dripping from the clothes.
> The clothes are dripping water.

If the clothes have just been picked up out of the washing tub and there is a *lot* of water:

> Water is running off the clothes.

If you are deliberately manipulating the clothing to force water out:

> Water is being wrung from the clothes.

Comment: ...and a garment made of a non-absorbent fabric, so that the water runs straight out when it's hung up and it needs little or no ironing, is described as _drip-dry_.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it.